# Android build failed: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I'm new to Android development and keep running into this specific error when I try building my test app via the Windows command: `python setup.py android -s`:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'
>
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1.

So how *do* I resolve all files for configuration?

---

After several hours of troubleshooting, related answers to this question have not worked for me. For instance, I have tried manipulating my `build.gradle` file in the following manner:

- Modified `maven()` to `maven {url "https://maven.google.com" }`
- Modified `jcenter()` to `jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }`
- Moved `jcenter...` to be the last item in the list under `repositories { ...`. (there is no `allprojects { ...` category)
- Added `buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"` under `android { ....`
- Modified the `classpath` version to the latest gradle version 3.1.0 like so `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'` (it was initially using an out of date version)

  ---
- Updated Android Studio IDE
- Uninstalled and reinstalled ***all*** `SDK-tools` under the `SDK Manager`

(Full `build.gradle` [here](https://pastebin.com/wFanU9Ub), on pastebin)

The only remaining helpful hint I have here is the information provided by the log.

It tells me that it can't find files *in directories on my hard drive*. All other related outputs I've seen from others is the location specifiying actual websites related to google or gradle.

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/appcompat-v7-25.1.1.pom
      file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/appcompat-v7-25.1.1.jar
      file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/appcompat-v7-25.1.1.pom
      file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/appcompat-v7-25.1.1.jar
      file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/appcompat-v7-25.1.1.pom
      file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/appcompat-v7-25.1.1.jar
```

I also have this error, which may or may not contribute to the files not being in the specified directory:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue and essentially resolve all files for configuration so that I can run my test app? Any help is greatly appreciated. Feel free to let me know if there's any additional I can provide.